# sharing a specific image from slider made by viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-viewpager

I have made image slider using viewPager and picasso. Images are loaded from my own(raw). I've put share button below image.

I want to make specific image be shared using share intent. I mean, if I'm in image of position 3 then only image of position 3 should be shared.

Activity where image slider is shown:

```java
public class RajeshDaiActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ViewPager viewPager;

    private int[] imageUrls = new int[]{

            R.drawable.oq,
            R.drawable.oqqqq,

            R.drawable.opt3
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rajesh_dai);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        ImageView ShareButton = findViewById(R.id.share);
        ShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent share = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                //?? how??
            }
        });
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code posted above, it looks like you need to implement an interface and capture the click event of the particular image and implement the logic for redirection in overridden implementation of the particular function in your fragment class. Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: If the case is that there is only one share button and multiple images, then in that case you would need to implement the above logic posted and get the image back from adapter and then use it for the redirection logic

Comment: I'm beginner in this, please say step by step procedure to follow? please?